# No data received in POST

Tags: html, forms, jsp, post

I am trying to upload a file to server. Here is my form code.

```
<form method="POST" action="<%request.getContextPath();%>/OPMS/webl" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="hidden" name="handler" value="fileupload" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="${dev.getUserId()}" />
<input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="openFileChooser();"><em class="fa"></em> Choose File</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><em class="fa fa-upload"></em> Upload </button>
</form>
```

The problem is i can't get data from the attributes. When i check the handler it return null. But if i change method to `GET` i can view the parameters in the request correctly but get won't work for the type of form enctype used.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? we need to see the code you are using to try and receive the file.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception when I try request. getParameter("handler").equals("fileupload")

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get the job done, I recommend Ravishanker Kusuma's `Hayageek jQuery File Upload plugin`:

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

He breaks down the process into three simple steps, that basically look like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  // (1)
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>   // (1)
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>  // (2)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({  // (3)
                url:"my_php_processor.php",
                fileName:"myfile"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The final step is to have the PHP file specified in the jQuery code (in this case `my_php_processor.php`) to receive and process the file:

**my_php_processor.php:**

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    $theFile = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
```

*Note the relationship between `myfile` in the PHP (`$_FILES["myfile"]`), and the filename specified in the jQuery code block.*

Comment: I am using jsp.. So what type must be theFile??

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed that in your code, and it should have been specified in the question (tags). This solution might not work for you.